# jquery ui accordion header height issue when used with google sidebar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-apps-script

I am just trying to use the default jQuery ui accordion in the sidebar.  It works but the header height is taller than the demo site, and I would prefer it to be smaller. I looked through the jquery-ui.css file and I am not able to find where to set the height of the header.

1. Where do I set the height of the header?
2. Is there an issue with the Google sidebar and accordion height.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding this style declaration to your sidebar's htlm will fix the issue:

```
<style>
caja-v-body {font-size:62.5%;}
</style>
```

It made the header height 13px just like in demo on http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ in my test.

[image: jQuery UI Accordion in Sheets Sidebar]